# Delay a python function call on a different pod

Tags: python, kubernetes, distributed

I have a piece of software deployed to Kubernetes, and in that I have a scenario when I want to have one function called at a later point in time, but I am not sure my current pod will be the one executing it (it may be scaled down, for example).

So I need help with a mechanism that will enable me to schedule a function for later, on a pod of my software that may or may not be the one that scheduled it, and also a way to decide *not* to do the execution if some condition was met ahead of time.

Also - I need this to be enabled for *thousands* of such calls at any given point in time, this is a very fast execution software using Twisted python working on millions of tasks a day. But given the scaling up and down, I cannot just put it on the reactor for later.

Almost any use of a known module, external redis/db is fine.

So - I need this community's help...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is very vague and seems more about system design than programming

Comment: Have you considered https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/ and what problems did you get?

Comment: To drum - not a design issue, or at least not a whole design issue. The problem was written in a vague way as I tried to keep it simple and not flood with irrelevant details (which I think might help others with other scenarios where they need to delay a task that is done by another entity in the system.

Comment: To Jonas - a job doesn't match here as the concept of a job is to run until exhausted its need - which never happens in my case. But even with jobs - K8S may decide to relocate them to a different node and the in-memory stuff is lost. So I need a stateless solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are roughly speaking describing any worker queue system, with Celery as the most common one in Python. With RabbitMQ as the broker it can easily scale to whatever traffic you throw at it. Also check out Dask but I think Dask is baaaaaad so I mention it only for completeness.